# PIN password: possibilities with several users in an attempt.

Tags: probability

I have a $4$-digit PIN and a list "user:pin". The possibility of guest the PIN's user is \frac{1}{10.000}. Example: user1:0001. But if I try 10.000 user at the same time what is the possiblity?. Example: user1:0000, user2:0001, ..., user10000:9999.

Is it something like the birthday paradox?.

Comment: The possibility of what? Finding at leaast one password or finding all of them?

Comment: The birthday "paradox" is that it's more likely that two persons have the same birthday than what one could intuitively guessed (not that some person would have a specific birthday). I don't really see the point here - the situation doesn't seem to be the same. Basically if you have random distribution and select a random PIN, there's about $e^{-1}$ (actually ${(9999/10000)}^{10000}$) risk that no-one had that PIN.

Comment: The possibility of find just one correct user-PIN. If I do an attempt to guest the PIN with "an user and a pin" I have 1/10.000 but If i do an attempt with "10.000 users and radom PINs or serial PINs (0001,0002,...)" the possibility is?. Thanks! ;)

Comment: I think your "possibility" stands for "probability".

Comment: @lin9 If PINs are assigned randomly from all possible 4-digit codes and independently for each user, it doesn't make a difference whether you use random, serial or fixed PIN guesses.

Comment: Yes, It is probability. @kviiri you are right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of zero correct guesses is

$$p_n=\left(\frac{9999}{10000}\right)^n$$

where $n$ is the number of guesses. You can see that $p_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, however it may take some time to reach low values.

For $n=10000$, the probability of having zero correct guesses is about $37\%$, so there is a probability of $63\%$ of guessing at leas one password.

Comment: Where I can find more information about this "kind of probability"?. I have to learn statistics... So with 10.000 users and 10.000 random PINs I have a probability of find at least 1 correct "user-pin" of 63%, right?.

Comment: @lin9 Any good probability textbook should give you this kind of knowledge, just keep doing the exercises!

Comment: It is binomial probability, right?.http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2810000+choose+1%29+*+%281%2F10000%29%5E1+*+%281+-+1%2F10000%29%5E%2810000-1%29

Answer (score 1):

The possibility that you find at least one PIN is $1 - .9999^{10000} \approx 1 - e^{-1}$. The reasoning is that the probability that you misguess a PIN is $.9999$ so misguessing $10000$ independent PINS will be $.9999^{10000}$. You will guess correctly at least once if you don't misguess them all.

Comment: It might a bit more illuminating to point out that the reason this is so close to $1-e^{-1}$ is that $(1-\frac1k)^k\to e^{-1}$, and here $k=10000$. But unlike the limit itself, since choosing the PIN codes from a fixed length, the more users you check, the greater is the chance that you hit a correct code.